Azure DevOps and SonarQube integration fails
I'm using community edition of SonarQube on my Ubuntu machine and self-hosted agent in Azure DevOps. I tried to integrate SonarQube in the pipeline using 2 different codes but none seems to be working.
1st pipeline
steps:
- task: SonarQubePrepare@5
  inputs:
    SonarQube: 'name_of_service_connection'
    scannerMode: 'Other'
    extraProperties: |
      # Additional properties that will be passed to the scanner,
      # Put one key=value per line, example:
      # sonar.exclusions=**/*.bin
      sonar.projectKey=my_sonar_project_key
      sonar.projectName=my_project_name

- script: |
    java -version
    wget https://builds.openlogic.com/downloadJDK/openlogic-openjdk/17.0.10+7/openlogic-openjdk-17.0.10+7-linux-x64.tar.gz -O JAVA_HOME_17_X64.tar.gz
    tree
  displayName: Download JDK17

- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '17'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    jdkSourceOption: 'LocalDirectory'
    jdkFile: 'JAVA_HOME_17_X64.tar.gz'
    jdkDestinationDirectory: '$(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/JAVA_HOME_17/X64'
    cleanDestinationDirectory: true
    createExtractDirectory: false


- script: |
    java -version
    echo Environment Variable JAVA_HOME_17_X64 is $(JAVA_HOME_17_X64)
    tree $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)
  displayName: Check JDK version

- task: Gradle@3
  inputs:
    gradleWrapperFile: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/gradlew'
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)'
    tasks: 'build'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.17' # Use pre-installed JAVA17
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: true
    sqGradlePluginVersionChoice: 'specify'
    sonarQubeGradlePluginVersion: '5.0.0.4638'
    spotBugsAnalysis: false
    
- task: SonarQubePublish@5
  condition: always()
  inputs:
    pollingTimeoutSec: '300'

but this is the error that I receive:

warning: No analyses found in this build! Please check your build configuration.

2nd pipeline
steps:
- script: |
    java -version
    wget https://builds.openlogic.com/downloadJDK/openlogic-openjdk/17.0.10+7/openlogic-openjdk-17.0.10+7-linux-x64.tar.gz -O JAVA_HOME_17_X64.tar.gz
    tree
  displayName: Download JDK17

- task: SonarQubePrepare@5
  displayName: Prepare SonarQube
  condition: always()
  inputs:
    SonarQube: 'name_of_service_connection'
    scannerMode: 'CLI'
    configMode: 'file'
    extraProperties: |
      sonar.projectKey= my_sonar_project_key
      sonar.projectName=$(SONAR_PREFIX_KEY)-$(app-name):$(app-name)
      sonar.branch.name='$(SonarBranchName)'
      sonar.host.url= my_sonar_url
      sonar.login= my_sonar_token

- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '17'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    jdkSourceOption: 'LocalDirectory'
    jdkFile: 'JAVA_HOME_17_X64.tar.gz'
    jdkDestinationDirectory: '$(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/JAVA_HOME_17/X64'
    cleanDestinationDirectory: true
    createExtractDirectory: false

- script: |
    java -version
    echo Environment Variable JAVA_HOME_17_X64 is $(JAVA_HOME_17_X64)
    tree $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)
  displayName: Check JDK version

- task: Gradle@3
  inputs:
    gradleWrapperFile: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/gradlew'
    workingDirectory: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)'
    tasks: 'build'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '1.17' # Use pre-installed JAVA17
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: true
    sqGradlePluginVersionChoice: 'specify'
    sonarQubeGradlePluginVersion: '5.0.0.4638'
    spotBugsAnalysis: false


- task: SonarQubeAnalyze@5
  condition: always()
  displayName: Run SonarQube analysis

- task: SonarQubePublish@5
  displayName: 'Publish SonarQube analysis'
  condition: always()
  inputs:
    pollingTimeoutSec: '300'

- task: sonar-buildbreaker@8
  condition: and(succeeded(),eq(variables.ableToScan, 'true'))
  displayName: "Evaluate SonarQube results"
  inputs:
    SonarQube: 'name_of_service_connection'

I end up by receiving

warning : This task was configured to use Java 11, but the SonarQube server v10.5.0 does not support it. Ignoring the configuration and using JAVA_HOME instead. Specify jdkversion in your task definition to use Java 17 to remove this warning.


error : Not authorized. Please check the user token in the property 'sonar.token' or the credentials in the properties 'sonar.login' and 'sonar.password'.

Although I have verified the permissions and the token from SonarQube and added my credentials in sonarqube.properties. But, the one created by Gradle only contains Default SonarQube server and Default source code encoding
Note that the Gradle@3 task always fails. How can I skip failed tests or find other solution?

Glad to see you in Stack overflow. Notice you have raised same ticket before, it's recommended to track the issue on one ticket, thanks.
